# MySQLi Insert and checking num_rows via $result = mysqli_query();

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mysqli

I have reviewed plenty of the answers written by you guys for the problem of mysqli query, num_rows and insert. I have already done this before on mysql (procedural maybe?) where there was no mysqli or pdo in any kind. After surfing the web why the mysql itself going out from "trend" I'm back to rewrite my code to mysqli. Note that I did this basic register/login stuff a year ago and now I'm fully lost.

Here is my code built from 2 files, config.php and account.php:

**config.php:**

```
<?php

// DB Settings
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "username";
$password = "password";
$dbname = "dbname";

// Connect to DB
$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

// Signals if there is an error 
if (!$conn) {
    die ("Something went wrong.");
}
```

I would notice that I do not close the connection as I use it in my account.php, see code below. If it might work finally I think it's ok if I do the mysqli_close($conn); before my ?> closing tag.

**account.php**

```
<?php

require 'config.php';

// Get session variables from input
$address = $_POST['address'];
$password = $_POST['password'];
$pin = $_POST['pin'];

// Starts the query for num_rows function ??
$result = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM Users WHERE address='($_POST['address'])'");

if(isset($_POST)) { // Checks if Submit (button) is true
    if (strlen($address) > 26 && strlen($address) < 35) { // Validates that the variable 'address' is in between the range specified.
        if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
            echo "Yay, u are registered!";
other code..
        } else {
        mysqli_query($conn, "INSERT INTO Users (address, password, pin) VALUES ('$address')");
        }
    }
    if (!filter_var($pin), FILTER_VALIDATE_INT) === false) {
        mysqli_query($conn, "INSERT INTO Users (address, password, pin) VALUES ('$pin')");
        }
mysqli_query($conn, "INSERT INTO Users (address, password, pin) VALUES ('$password')");
}

$mysqli->close();
?>
```

I'd use this simple stuff to check if the data from the input fields are already exist if not then insert it into the db. That would be all I need but I haven't do coding for a long time..

My website returns nothing as it gives me an 500 internal error. If I remove the whole PHP code from account.php it gives me a "something went wrong" message from the config.php die() response. I made somewhere a mistake or syntax error but hell yes I just cant find it for more than 2 hours now ..

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What error is in your error.log?

Comment: 1. There is no error handling in your code around your sql calls, so you cannot figure out what goes wrong.  Never ever assume that things always go right. Assume the opposite. 2. You cannot use `$_POST['address']` the way you do it in the 1st sql call, that's probably a reason for the error. Use prepared statements with parameter binding or at least properly concatenate your sql commands as strings.

Comment: I modified it to:
$result = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM Users WHERE address='$address'");
Is this correct if I put it in ' ' letters and call the variable as $address?

Comment: Insert statements are not valid